# Find using Grep everywthing that starts with "country=" but not "country=US"

Tags: grep

I'm running `varnishlog | grep "country="` but I want to find all traffic not originating in US.

I need something using `OR` and `NOT` .

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like

```
varnishlog | grep "country=" | grep -v "country=US"
```

**grep -v** is grep inverse, it will return lines **not** matching the text

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression solution to this problem is a "negative lookahead". `country=(?!us)` matches `country=` whenever it is not followed by `us`.